# SQL Server WITH x AS Incorrect Syntax

Tags: sql-server, join, syntax

I'm trying to run a query to select all orders, but also display the client/customer name from a second table, plus the last invoice date from a third table. Initially I was just doing an `INNER JOIN` to get the invoice date, however that only showed orders that had invoices (I need to include orders without invoices too, so I know a right/left join should've been used instead), but the second issue was that it was showing orders with multiple invoices multiple times. E.g. if an order had 3 different invoice dates there'd be a row for each, rather than one row with the last invoice date.

I'm trying to use this query now instead to get the correct data

```
WITH inv AS 
(
    SELECT 
        CASE moi.orderNumber,
        MAX(moi.datePosted) lastInvoiceDate 
    FROM 
        tblManOrderInvoices moi 
    GROUP BY moi.orderNumber
) 
SELECT 
    CASE mo.orderNumber, 
    c.companyName, 
    inv.lastInvoiceDate 
FROM 
    tblManOrders mo 
LEFT JOIN 
    tblClients c ON mo.clientId = c.clientId 
LEFT JOIN 
    inv ON mo.orderNumber = inv.orderNumber 
WHERE 
    ISNULL(mo.isDeleted, 0) = 0 
ORDER BY 
    mo.orderNumber
```

But I get an error (two, but the same error in different places)

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near ','.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   Incorrect syntax near ','.

What is wrong with my query that is causing it to fail?

Comment: `CASE moi.orderNumber, MAX(moi.datePosted)`? Where's the rest of yoru `CASE` expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `CASE` is unnecessary, :

```
WITH inv AS (
     SELECT moi.orderNumber, MAX(moi.datePosted) as lastInvoiceDate 
     FROM tblManOrderInvoices moi 
     GROUP BY moi.orderNumber
) 
 SELECT  mo.orderNumber, c.companyName, inv.lastInvoiceDate 
 FROM tblManOrders mo LEFT JOIN 
      tblClients c 
      ON mo.clientId = c.clientId LEFT JOIN 
      inv 
      ON mo.orderNumber = inv.orderNumber 
 WHERE mo.isDeleted IS NOT NULL 
 ORDER BY mo.orderNumber;
```